# Bootstrap lower resolutions rules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I understand that if I define a bootstrap 3 column with a lower resolution (e.g. col-sm-6), higher resolutions will have the same value as that column (6).

But what about the lower resolutions? Suppose I have a column defined as "col-lg-6", what will happen with devices with lower resolution? They have the same value or take some default ?

Comment: **They have the same value or take some default** correct, they have default and they won't take the stylings made for col-lg-6. I believe bootstrap use media queries to differentiate stylings with sm, md, and lg

Comment: @JF-Mechs what is the default value? any reference? Thank you!

Comment: Just to confirm, please enlighten me, what do you mean **lower resolution** ? do you mean a lower screen size e.g., phones and tablets?

Comment: @JF-Mechs yes: xs,sm,md screen sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap columns from xs (extra small) to lg (large) e.g., **col-xs-1** to **col-lg-12**
takes a CSS style of

```
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

In your example:
if you defined an element with a css class **col-lg-6**
e.g., `<div class="col-lg-6">`
which has a styling under

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-6 {
   width: 50%;
}
```

the css in it won't take effect on a lower than media screen size of 1200px

Another example..

Let say you added an element:

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div>`

notice the 3 css class added.

by default your `div` tag now takes those style mention above.

but they do response/react when screen size changes.

Bootstrap uses **MEDIA QUERIES**

`@media (min-width: 768px) // for sm(small) columns.`

this means elements with class **col-sm-** overwrite or add a css when device size is 768px and above
e.g.,

```
.col-sm-6 {
   width: 50%;
   background:red; //this is just an example.
}
```

but..

Bootstrap again declares a media queries on md (medium)

```
@media (min-width: 992px)

.col-md-6 {
   width: 50%;
   background:blue: //this is just an example.
}
```

basically it ignores the css `background:red` of column-sm and overwrite it by `background:blue` when device screen size change to 992px

and so on and so forth.

You can check the css of bootstrap in this [link](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) and you can also go their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to learn more about their grid system.